# How do I implement the Guardian Egyptian font family in my website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I really want to use this [font](https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/e3ffc95b0c8347688409fe4c6aa92a32_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1431090000&s=a535e5f9198565d26211f288054f432b) in my website. In CSS, this font is not accepted, why?

```
p{
    font-family: Guardian Egyptian;
}
```

[See here](https://jsfiddle.net/xyc592hy/)

Comment: Your result is not opening.

Comment: You have to refer the font path in your css.

Comment: Anand j. Kadhi, its opening now.

Comment: You have to refer that font path. https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/guardian/egyptian_text

Comment: I think you can download it from http://www.typewolf.com/site-of-the-day/fonts/guardian Or http://labaseweb.com/wp-content/downloads/guardian-egyptian-font.php

Comment: hi Ketan, how can I refer that in my coding? It seems that its not free to use. is it?

Comment: @Munira try second two link to download it free.

Comment: @Munira you can link font like: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Comment: thank u Ketan, I have followed the tutorial but I have confusion about the font-face and how the source link is used there. I have refrred the link exactly. If you see here then see it doesn't do anything. https://jsfiddle.net/r1gcbxp3/

Comment: You have to download that font into your local and you have to set it's path after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why font-face rules don't work in my paragraph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125097/why-font-face-rules-dont-work-in-my-paragraph)

Answer (score 1):

You could  declare a new custom remote font to be used like so for eg:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Guardian Egyptian;
  src: url(Guardian Egyptian.ttf');
}
```

Comment: ᴀʀᴜn BᴇrtiL, I am frustrated to figure out the way. where do u get the url: Guardian Egyptian.ttf? where does it exist online? and moreover I tried, but it didnt work.

Comment: You download the font, put it on your server, and set the path on your CSS. To get the remote file you need a service that provides it.

Comment: But note that Guardian Egyptian is **not** a free font you can just use when you feel like it. While you *could* download it from a website that also uses it and then use it on your own website, you'd *also* be breaking the law because you don't have the rights to use that font. You'll have to buy that right over at https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/guardian