# Why font-face rules don't work in my paragraph?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to implement `Guardian Egyptian` font-family in my website. I have implemented font-face rules for remote referring. But in CSS it doesn't work. In fact, it doesn't change the font into `Guardian Egyptian`. Why?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hzny3gx3/) is what I have tried:

Comment: Please post the pertinent code in the question. Fiddles should be supplementary but not compulsory to understanding the question.

Comment: Your src URL is only pointing to a webpage to purchase the fonts. Not to a font file itself. Have you purchases the font? Normally when you buy a font it comes with instructions on how to implement it.

Comment: Your font src is to page where you buy the font lol (https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/guardian/egyptian_text)

Answer (score 5):

You can't just put a random URL in a `font-face` call and expect it to work. That's a link to a site where you can *purchase* that font. When purchased, they'd give you a webfont-ready version of the font for use on your site.

Comment: what is the alternative way of buying. I dont want to buy but I want to use this font in my website. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: It's a paid font. You buy it, or you don't use it.